# Graphic novel about a spaceship crash landing on a planet, and the stranded inhabitants of the ship forming a colony and a new society there

Tags: story-identification, novel, comics, space-colonization

I have been looking for this book for quite some time.  I recall starting to read it in the late '70s.  It was a color graphic novel.

At the beginning of the novel, there was a crash landing of a spaceship and it was determined that there was no way to repair the ship and leave the planet.  A huge amount of people were on the ship and so it was decided to colonize the planet.  There was a vote to elect one of three candidates to lead the civilization, and I remember everyone voting by throwing a colored stone in the valley, representing the person they voted for.

I'm not sure if the novel is a stand-alone book or a series of graphic novels.  Any help in locating it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just pointing out that the inhabitants of the planet  We Made It in Larry Niven's Known Space universe are called "[Crashlanders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crashlander)".

Comment: Sounds like badly remembered The Trigan Empire - it begins with a spaceship crashing on Earth and has the voting scene on early pages.

Comment: Dragan That's exactly it!!!  I've been looking for this book for 40 years!  I can't thank you enough!

Comment: @DraganMilosevic If you post your answer as an Answer rather than as a comment on the question, the poster can mark it as the accepted Answer, and you can get credit for it.